# Custom self-closing / unpaired tags in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing, html4

The following code [[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CUZta/)]...

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "<foo>This is a <bar /> test. <br> Another test.</foo>";
alert(div.innerHTML);
```

...shows this parsed structure:

```
<foo>This is a <bar> test. <br> Another test.</bar></foo>
```

i.e. the browser knows that `<br>` has no closing tag but since `<bar>` is an unknown tag to the browser, it assumes that it needs an closing tag.

I know that the `/>` (solidus) syntax is ignored in HTML5 and invalid in HTML4, but anyway would like to teach somehow the browser that `<bar>` does not need an ending tag and I can omit it. **Is that possible?**

*Yes, I'm trying to (temporarily) misuse the HTML code for custom tags and I have my specific reasons to do that. After all, browsers should ignore unknown tags and treat them just like unstyled inline tags, so I should not break anything as long I can make sure the tag names won't ever be used in real HTML standards.*

Answer (score 8):

You'd have to use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) on HTMLElement.prototype to override the innerHTML setter and getter with your own innerHTML implementation that treats the elements you want as [void](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements). Look [here](http://html5.org/specs/dom-parsing.html#innerhtml) for how innerHTML and the HTML parser is implemented by default.

Note though that Firefox sucks at inheritance when it comes to defining stuff on HTMLElement.prototype where it filters down to HTMLDivElement for example. Things should work fine in Opera though.

In other words, what elements are void depends on the HTML parser. The parser follows [this list](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements) and innerHTML uses the same rules mostly.

So, in other words, unless you want to create your own innerHTML implementation in JS, you probably should just forget about this.

You can use the [live DOM viewer](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/) though to show others how certain markup is parsed. You'll then probably notice that same end tags will implicitly close the open element.

I have some outdated innerHTML getter (not setter though) code [here](http://shadow2531.com/js/) that uses a void element list. That may give you some ideas. But, writing a setter implementation might be more difficult.

On the other hand, if you use createElement() and appendChild() etc. instead of innerHTML, you shouldn't have to worry about this and the native innerHTML getter will output the unknown elements with end tags.

Note though, you can treat the unknown element as xml and use XMLSerializer() and DOMParser() to do things:

```
var x = document.createElement("test");
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
alert(serializer.serializeToString(x));
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString("<test/>", "application/xml");
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.appendChild(document.importNode(doc.documentElement, true));
alert(serializer.serializeToString(div));
```

It's not exactly what you want, but something you can play with. (Test that in Opera instead of Firefox to see the difference with xmlns attributes. Also note that Chrome doesn't do like Opera and Firefox.)

Comment: Thanks for all the useful references. I'm using innerHTML for two reasons: first, because it is a pretty fast and tolerant parser. Second, because my goal is not to rely on innerHTML but also allow using an existing DOM subtree. This implies that the browser itself must accept new void tags, if that's possible at all. --- As a side note, I'm wondering how it would be possible to add new **void** tags to, say, the HTML6+ standard since they would apparently confuse all HTML5- parsers...

Comment: @UdoG Added a little something you can play with.