# Change the interior of the div by pressing the button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div in which depending on the button I press I put a html code inside or another.

I have made the addEventListener with a helloworld and when I press it, it puts it inside perfectly, but when I try to put this html, what should appear does not appear.

```
document.querySelector(".grafica-today").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector(".grafica-recipiente").innerHTML = "<canvas id='graficaDiaria'><script src='js/graficDiaria.js'></script></canvas>";
});
```

The case is that if I put this code and I enter in the page if it appears correctly the interior of the js, but when doing it by means of the button it does not work. It is as if you put it, but do not execute it (I don't know if I'm making myself clear).

```
<div class="col-md-9 grafica-recipiente">
     <canvas id="graficaMundial">
          <script src="js/graficaMundial.js"></script>
     </canvas>
</div>
```

The initial code is the same as the one I am trying to add, but it is displayed correctly, but when I click on the button, it is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The [innerHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property is adding closing tags for your `<script>` element even though you have already added your own. Just use a self-closing tag and append the closing `</canvas>` tag after like this:

```js
const graficaBtn = document.querySelector('.grafica-today');
const graficaR = document.querySelector('.grafica-recipiente');

graficaBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  graficaR.innerHTML = "<canvas id='graficaDiaria'><script src='https://js/graficDiaria.js'/>";
  graficaR.innerHTML += "</canvas>";
});
```

```html
<button class="grafica-today">Click Me</button>
<div class="col-md-9 grafica-recipiente"></div>
```

**N.B.** Check this other [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728671/javascript-innerhtml-changes-auto-close-tags/26728777) as well as this other [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094190/custom-self-closing-unpaired-tags-in-html) for a more in-depth explanation on why innerHTML tries to add it's own closing tags and how that can be a problem with self-closing custom tags as well.

Comment: It seems that using an open `<script>` tag and omitting the `graficaR.innerHTML += "</canvas>";` line works too as `innerHTML` will automatically add the closing tags for you but for readability's sake, I think you should still use the self-closing `<script/>` tag and add the closing `</canvas>` tag regardless.